# (Clion, macOS) Matplotlib: Undefined symbols for M1 MacBook, ARM64

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, clion, apple-silicon

I'm trying to get Matplotlib working in C++ on macOS using Clion as I need to plot 2D graphs. However, after getting over some issues with setting a path for headers: `Python.h` and `arrayobject.h`, I cannot get over following error: `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64`, namely,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_PyCObject_AsVoidPtr", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyCObject_Type", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyErr_Format", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyErr_Print", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::import_numpy() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyErr_SetString", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::import_numpy() in main.cpp.o
      _import_array() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyExc_AttributeError", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyExc_ImportError", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::import_numpy() in main.cpp.o
      _import_array() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyExc_RuntimeError", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyFunction_Type", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyImport_Import", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyImport_ImportModule", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyObject_CallMethod", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyObject_CallObject", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::colorbar() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyObject_GetAttrString", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
      _import_array() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyString_FromString", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
  "_PyTuple_New", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::~_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
  "_Py_SetProgramName", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [untitled] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [untitled] Error 2
```

My main file (an example I took from Matplotlib files):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
#include <vector>

namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

int main() {
    std::vector<double> y = {1, 3, 2, 4};
    plt::plot(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Matplotlib.cpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint> // <cstdint> requires c++11 support
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

#include </System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h>

#ifndef WITHOUT_NUMPY
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include </System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h>
#endif // WITHOUT_NUMPY
```

**Please, note**: The main purpose of my programme in C++ was to solve "some" PDEs system, which I already accomplished, and I know that it works (I checked the plotted curves trends (convergence etc.) and values in *MS Excel*), however, plotting the values in *MS Excel* is very slow, hence counter-productive.

I don't have experiences with plotting 2D graphs in C++. So, if there is any easier way (library etc.) to plot 2D graphs in C++ (macOS, Clion, amr64 M1), I don't need to stick with Matplotlib.

Thanks

Comment: You're including a header, but not linking against the framework. For the record, you should never have to specify a path like that. `<Python/Python.h>` should suffice, if you have `-framework Python` on the command line, or whatever the Xcode equivalent is.

Comment: Including the header such as I did was I every example by Matplotlib for C++. Could you be please more specific? As for the `<Python/Python.h>`, I had that before, both works - I was just "trying" in order to see whether the remaining error will be solved.